# POST to mongodb through URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to post data to a mongo DB through a URL of a browser. I was able to get it working using only expressJS, but I am having difficulty getting it working with mongodb. I'm still very new to this, so I am hoping that I am just missing a simple component and that I am at least on the right track.

When I enter "http://localhost:27017/api/users?id=4&token=sdfa3" or "http://localhost:27017/nodetest5/api/users?id=4&token=sdfa3" into the url, I'd like to see "4 sdfa3" on the webpage. Right now I am just getting a webpage with the message: "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."

Here is my server.js file:

```
// packages
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//db stuff
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest5');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded

//make accessible mongo db accessible to router
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
})

// routes 
app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    //get values from URL
    var id = req.param('id');
    var token = req.param('token');
    res.send(user_id + ' ' + token + ' ');
});

// POST to localhost
// parameters sent with
app.post('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    //internal DB value
    var db = req.db;

    //values from URL
    var user_id = req.body.id;
    var token = req.body.token;

    //set collection
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');

    //Submit to DB
    collection.insert({
        "id" : id,
        "token" : token
    }, function (err, doc){
        if (err) {
            res.send("Error encountered when trying to add entry to database.");
        }
        else {
            res.send(user_id + ' ' + token + ' ');
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP interface for MongoDB can be accessed via port number `28017`. You'll need to provide the `--rest` option to `mongod`:

```
`$ mongod --rest`
```

You can read more in the [HTTP Interface documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface).

You should exercise caution when using the HTTP interface. From the MongoDB documentation:

> WARNING
>   Ensure that the HTTP status interface, the REST API, and the JSON API are all disabled in production environments to prevent potential data exposure and vulnerability to attackers.

Comment: Thanks for the response, though I'm not sure how this will help me achieve a POST through the URL. I tried starting mongod with `mongod --rest` but I haven't gotten any different results, other than being able to connect  to `http://localhost:28017/`

Comment: You cannot make a `POST` request through the URL. https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api

Comment: What if I were to use something like monk like I am trying to use above? Or is there simply no workaround?